# Hypergraphdb weighted rdf property

Tags: graph, rdf, hypergraphdb

I came across hypergraphdb, it seems interesting. But How to represent weighted rdf property and higher order relationships in hypergraphdb?

Comment: Can you show what you've got sofar and where you are stuck? As-is the question is rather too broad.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: thanks for replying. I have successfully set-up the hypergraphdb. but I would like to know how to load Ontologies(such as OWL/RDFS) and write instances (similar to RDF Data) which follows the Ontology. Also, the main reason for choosing hypergraphdb is that it supports higher order relationships (edges) between graph nodes. I need that feature to represent RDF Property with weighted values. For example: if [A-likes->B] then I would like to attach a weight to the 'likability'. I haven't found an example that does just that so far. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'm in the same situation as you too. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about HypergraphDB, but you don't need higher-order relationships to support attaching weights to properties. There are several practical approaches for doing that within the RDF standard, either by using a form of reification, or by using the named graph/context/quad mechanism available in most RDF databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can add values to relations with the HGValueLink method:

```
HGHandle relationLink = hyperGraph.add(new HGValueLink("my-string-identifier", startHandle, endHandle));
```

"my-string-value" is a String object but you could add an Integer or any other object to the relation.